# iMac 2011 With Yosemite kernel panics several times

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

Our Mac has kernel panicked about 5 times today.
Below is the crash log if someone could help us out, cheers in advance.

```
> Anonymous UUID:       2FBA36C0-0496-067C-BFC9-151393EB378C
> 
> Wed Aug 12 13:08:40 2015
> 
> *** Panic Report *** panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff802a017cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80a9f1c240, type 14=page fault, registers: CR0:
> 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff80a9f1c240, CR3: 0x0000000000a53038,
> CR4: 0x00000000000626e0 RAX: 0x0000000000000023, RBX:
> 0xffffff8045d596d0, RCX: 0xffffff8045de1108, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
> RSP: 0xffffff803b2b3eb8, RBP: 0xffffff803b2b3ef0, RSI:
> 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0xffffff8045dc4960 R8:  0xffffff8162ed5120,
> R9:  0xffffff803b2b3ec8, R10: 0x00007fff94e904de, R11:
> 0x0000000000000202 R12: 0xffffff8045dc4961, R13: 0xffffff802a601890,
> R14: 0xffffff8045dc4960, R15: 0xffffff8045dc4968 RFL:
> 0x0000000000010296, RIP: 0xffffff80a9f1c240, CS:  0x0000000000000008,
> SS:  0x0000000000000010 Fault CR2: 0xffffff80a9f1c240, Error code:
> 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU: 0x2
> 
> Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff803b2b3b60 :
> 0xffffff8029f2bda1  0xffffff803b2b3be0 : 0xffffff802a017cc2 
> 0xffffff803b2b3da0 : 0xffffff802a034b73  0xffffff803b2b3dc0 :
> 0xffffff80a9f1c240  0xffffff803b2b3ef0 : 0xffffff8029f24532 
> 0xffffff803b2b3f10 : 0xffffff802a0031ea  0xffffff803b2b3fb0 :
> 0xffffff802a035396 
> 
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
> 
> Mac OS version: 14E46
> 
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT
> 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
> E3C26B2F-8B97-3F1D-B193-690F7E34F830 Kernel slide:    
> 0x0000000029c00000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8029e00000
> __HIB  text base: 0xffffff8029d00000 System model name: iMac12,2 (Mac-942B59F58194171B)
> 
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 8362170621845 last loaded kext at
> 7923039275404: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC
> 4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7facd99000, size 20480) last unloaded kext at 7983061712345: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC
> 4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7facd99000, size 16384) loaded kexts: com.aladdin.kext.aksfridge
> 1.0.2 com.apple.filesystems.smbfs
> 3.0.1 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC
> 1.70 com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor
> 1.9.5d0 com.apple.driver.AGPM  110.19.6 com.apple.filesystems.autofs
> 3.0 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager
> 4.3.5f8 com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1 com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124
> com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver
> 272.18.1 com.apple.driver.AppleHDA
> 272.18.1 com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient
> 3.6.1 com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer
> 1.3.2 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet
> 1.0.1 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X
> 7.0.0 com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000  1.3.2 com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess 1 com.apple.driver.AppleHV  1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP
> 2.0.2 com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight
> 170.7.4 com.apple.driver.AppleLPC
> 1.7.3 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC
> 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU
> 2.0.7d0 com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl
> 1.2.12 com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller
> 1.3.2 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking
> 4.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics
> 10.0.0 com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin
> 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
> 4.3.5f8 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB
> 10.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleIRController
> 327.5 com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient
> 3.7.5 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader
> 3.5.5 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless
> 1.0.0d1 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib
> 1.0.0 com.apple.BootCache  36 com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage
> 2.7.1 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub
> 705.4.2 com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40
> 700.74.5 com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet
> 10.1.3 com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI
> 5.5.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI
> 705.4.14 com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort
> 3.1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC
> 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons
> 3.1 com.apple.driver.AppleHPET
> 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS
> 2.1 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC
> 3.1 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC
> 1.7 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient
> 218.0.0 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 161 com.apple.security.quarantine 3 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement
> 218.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard
> 176.2 com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver
> 4.3.5f8 com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard
> 176.2 com.apple.kext.triggers  1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib
> 272.18.1 com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib
> 1.15 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface
> 97.4 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2
> 156.16 com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert
> 1.1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient
> 705.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI
> 1.0.12d1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink
> 4.0.3 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController
> 1.0.13d1 com.apple.kext.AMDSupport
> 1.3.2 com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl
> 3.10.24 com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily
> 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP
> 2.2.6 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC
> 3.1.9 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy
> 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily
> 5.9.1d7 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
> 4.3.5f8 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily
> 4.3.5f8 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController
> 272.18.1 com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily
> 272.18.1 com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily
> 203.3 com.apple.vecLib.kext  1.2.0 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport
> 2.4.1 com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily
> 2.4.1 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice
> 3.7.5 com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily
> 1.7 com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily
> 1.7.1 com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily
> 1.7.1 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI
> 2.6.1 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver
> 705.4.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice
> 3.7.5 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass
> 3.7.2 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily
> 3.7.5 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub
> 705.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite
> 705.4.9 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter
> 4.0.6 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter
> 4.0.6 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily
> 4.0.6 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter
> 2.0.2 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI
> 3.1.7 com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily
> 4.2.2 com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family
> 730.60 com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController
> 1.0.3b3 com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient
> 1.0.1b8 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily
> 3.2 com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily
> 4.5.7 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily
> 2.7.5 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily
> 720.4.4 com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM
> 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime
> 2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily
> 2.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily
> 1.1 com.apple.security.sandbox
> 300.0 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch
> 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity
> 1.0.5 com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager
> 1.0 com.apple.driver.DiskImages 397 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily
>  2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31 com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore
> 28.30 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform
> 3.1 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily
> 2.9 com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily
> 1.4 com.apple.kec.Libm  1 com.apple.kec.pthread  1 com.apple.kec.corecrypto  1.0
```

It restarts and then we work on it and then say around an hour later it kernel panics again !

Answer (score 1):

The basic troubleshooting question is: When was the last time it *wasn't* having the kernel panic? What has *changed* on the system since then?

Usually some new piece of software has been downloaded and installed (wittingly or un-wittingly, or perhaps by someone else using the machine, without your knowledge), or some new peripheral has been connected to the computer, or some new client/server relationship has been established.

So ask yourself: "What has changed?".

The next step is to systematically un-install and remove the new thing or things and see if this corrects the problem.